# Is it possible to find such a discrete non-cyclic mathematical function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, discrete-mathematics, soft-question, research

Is it possible to find such a discrete non-cyclic function with the following features?

> Let $$f: \mathbb{Z^{+}} \rightarrow \left\{0,1,2 \right\},$$
>
> and for any $n\in\mathbb{Z^{+}},\left\{ f(3n-2),f(3n-1),f(3n)\right\}$
>   must be equal $\left\{0,1,2 \right\}$, or $\left\{
>  0,2,1\right\},\left\{1,2,0 \right\},\left\{1,0,2 \right\} \left\{2,1,0
>  \right\},\left\{ 2,0,1\right\}$.

Discrete non-cyclic means, for example:

$$\color{purple}{\left\{f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4),f(5),f(6),f(7),f(8),...f(n) \right\}:=}\color{red}{\left\{\color{red}{0,1,2,2,1,0,1,0,2;} \color{green}{0,1,2,2,1,0,1,0,2;} \color{blue}{0,1,2,2,1,0,1,0,2;}... \right\}}$$

Thus, we have discrete cyclic sequence. Because,

$f(9)=f(1), f(10)=f(2), f(11)=f(3),...,f(16)=f(8).$ In other words,
$f(n)=f(n-8)$, where $n≥9, n\in\mathbb{Z^{+}}$ and cycle length is equal to $8.$

I hope I'm asking the question clearly.

I am looking for a mathematical function that takes discrete non-cyclic values. I'm not saying to MSE "Find such a function." What I want to know is whether such a special function can exist mathematically.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, such a function "exists mathematically", and we can easily describe such a function.  For instance, take 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & x \text{ is a perfect square}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: The typical term for what you're calling "cyclic" is *periodic*.

Comment: Your question is completely unclear: why do you introduce the sets $D(f)$ and $E(f)$ but never mention then again? What is $n$ in the "definition" of $D(f)$. An example is an inadequate replacement for a definition, so we have no idea what you mean by "discrete non-cyclic" particularly as your example makes no sense: how do $f$ and $n$ on the left-hand side of the symbol ${:}{=}$ relate to the numbers on the right-hand side?

Comment: Concretely, the sequence I'm describing is 
$$
\{1,\overbrace{0,0}^2,1,\overbrace{0,\dots,0}^4,1,\overbrace{0,\dots,0}^6,1,\dots\}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: that's the set $\{0, 1\}$ - can we please introduce a little bit of rigour here and not conflate sequence and set notation.

Comment: I suppose $D(f)$ means the domain of $f$. But this is non-standard notation. And in any case, the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb Z^+$, not $\{1,2,3,4,5,\ldots,n\}$. And $E(f)$ means the range of $f$? (I can't think what $E$ stands for.) But if so, why not just write $f:\Bbb Z^+\to\{0,1,2\}$?

Comment: Disregard my previous comments; they don't match up with the latest explanation of the question

Comment: @TonyK Thank you very much for suggestion. I fixed.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I tried to fix the question.

Comment: But now in your example we have $(f(3),f(4),f(5))=(2,2,1)$, which violates your condition about $f(n),f(n+1),f(n+2)$ with $n=3$. Please try to clean this question up!

Comment: @Tonykn right, right You are right .. what I want to ask is obvious. But I didn't do it mathematically well. I'm fixing now.

Comment: @TonyK I fixed it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

Not only are such sequences easy to define (as shown in the comments to your post), but there are also some very cool ones that find applications elsewhere in mathematics. In particular, the [Thue-Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) is aperiodic, and even has a [ternary version](https://oeis.org/A053838).